# Photoshop Scripting array to json

Tags: javascript, json, photoshop

I want to get all the layers in a json document. 
Here is my code :

```
#include json2.js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var allLayers = [];
var allLayers = collectAllLayers(doc, allLayers);

function collectAllLayers (doc, allLayers){
    for (var m = 0; m < doc.layers.length; m++){
        var theLayer = doc.layers[m];
        if (theLayer.typename === "ArtLayer"){
            allLayers.push(theLayer);
        }else{
            collectAllLayers(theLayer, allLayers);
        }
    }
    return allLayers;
}
var json = JSON.stringify(allLayers);

alert(json);
```

My efforts `var json = JSON.stringify(allLayers);` doesn't working. I want to `allLayers` change to json.
Thanks for help answers in advance!

Comment: Please provide an example of contents of doc.layers for us to be able to help you.

Comment: can you tell us what isn't working with `var json = JSON.stringify(allLayers);` does it throw an error ? is `json` empty ?

Comment: What does the method `collectAllLayers(doc, allLayers);` return?

Comment: Is the code working at yours place? I am getting "General Photoshop error occurred.This functionality may not be avaliable in this version of photoshop"

Answer (score 1):

Some of the types Photoshop uses aren't supported by JSON (like `File` for instance), so JSONing some of the Photoshop DOM objects won't work. You'll need to modify `json2.js` or create your own parser that'll create a jsonable object.

Comment: why doesn't JSON support them ?

Comment: I don't know and I'm not a programmer enough to figure it out, this is just from experience. `document` has around 40 properties and on around 25 of them JSON throws a TypeError, however `typeof ` of those properties are `strings`

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy So there isn't chances to get layers in json document in my code?

Comment: You'll need to manually convert all unrecognizable data to jsonable data. For instance, JSON fails to JSONify `artLayer.bounds` property because this is an array of units (pixels, inches) which aren't available in json. So I guess you'll have to convert it to an array of numbers and maybe in another property write down the units. And so on.

Comment: if you check ArtLayer properties in the scripting guide https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf , you'll notice that while some of the properties are strings and booleans, some of them are Document, LayerKind, TextItem and so on, I imagine those are requred to be converted to jsonable types.